# SSIS Excel Source wont let me change DT_DATE to DT_WSTR

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, ssis-data-types

I have an SSIS package that imports data form an excel source to a SQL Server DB. The file has a column named `[Client Date Of Birth]` that is USUALLY a valid date. I say usually because the data is entered by our client's agents and can be anything from `02/24/2017` to `Feb 17` or even just `2017`. I actually need this data to come in as a string because we do partial comparison to these dates so data coming in as `Feb 2017` is still technically okay.

The problem is SSIS automatically determines that this column is of `[DT_DATE]` type. I try to change the DataType to `[DT_WSTR]` in the External columns section of the Advanced Editor for the source, but when i click OK, SSIS automatically switches it back to `[DT_DATE]`. How do I get SSIS to import this column as a string?

It should also be noted that this is an automatic process so I can't make any changes to the excel file itself because it will be replaced by a new file each week.

Comment: You can place a Data Conversion transformation component after the Source and use it to convert the [Client Date Of Birth] to String [DT_STR].

Comment: If POSSIBLE (I know it is mostly not), convert that column in excel to text.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this:

**First way**

- Add a script component
- Mark `[Client Date Of Birth]` as an Input Column
- Create an Output Column `[StrDOB]` with Datatype equal `[DT_STR]`
- In the script write the following code (*i assumed that you want the date format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`*):

  ```
  Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

      If Not Row.ClientDateOfBirth_IsNull Then
              Row.strDOB = Row.ClientDateOfBirth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
          Else
              Row.strDOB_IsNull = True
      End If

  End Sub
  ```

**Second Way**

Use a *Data Conversion Transformation* component to achieve this. Just follow this MSDN links to get Help:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141706.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140321.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186792.aspx